# Uso de maiúsculas e minúsculas a seguir aos pontos de interrogação e exclamação

Tags: ortografia, escrita

A seguinte frase de Eça de Queiros em «O Conde d'Abranhos)» <sup>1</sup>   ilustra o uso de maiúsculas a seguir aos pontos de interrogação e exclamação:

> (...) e quem esquecerá essa jóia da poesia portuguesa, que dedicou à sua morte o nosso grande lírico, o autor melodioso dos «Cânticos e Suspiros»**? Ah! Sr.ª** Condessa, recitemos ambos, na nossa dor comum, esta estrofe, (...)

Mas também se usam minúsculas, quando a oração (frase) que vem imediatamente a seguir é intercalada, como no exemplo seguinte, retirado da entrada "[Maiúsculas após os pontos de interrogação e de exclamação?](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/maiusculas-apos-os-pontos-de-interrogacao-e-de-exclamacao/31279)" do Ciberdúvidas.

> «É esta a gaveta**? — perguntou** ele.» (Osman Lins, O Visitante, 53)

Só se usam as minúsculas a seguir aos pontos de interrogação e exclamação,  quando a oração que se segue é intercalada, ou há algum caso mais subtil?

--

<sup>1</sup> Livros do Brasil, Lisboa, 2000, Obras Póstomas

Comment: Acho que é mais uma questão de licença poética.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Na língua portuguesa, todas as frases deverão começar com letra maiúscula, seja a anterior terminada em ponto final, ponto de interrogação ou ponto de exclamação. Nesse caso em particular a questão não se refere a uma frase normal mas sim a uma interrupção do narrador.

As regras indicam que se a interrupção do narrador for precedida por um ponto final (A) esta deverá começar igualmente por maiúscula, mas no caso de ser precedida por um ponto de exclamação (B) ou ponto de interrogação (C), a letra de início da frase deverá ser minúscula e utilizar no fim um ponto final.
No caso de a interrupção do narrador não ser precedida por nenhum ponto de exclamação ou de interrogação e se a fala tiver continuação depois da interrupção, deve-se utilizar a minúscula para começar a frase e não pontuar no fim (D).

Por exemplo:

B - Ele foi para a escola! – assegurou-me. - Não sei a que horas vem.
C - Ele foi para a escola? - repeti admirado. - Tem a certeza?
A – Claro que tenho. - Declarou.
D - Mas se ele foi para a escola – comecei, apesar de saber que tal não era verdade - não deveria ter levado a mochila que está ali pousada?

Mais informações aqui:

https://fanfiction.com.br/aula/27/Caminho_do_Ninja_Amador_missao_02_Meta_05_pontuacao_V_travessao

https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/maiusculas-e-minusculas-apos-sinais-de-pontuacao/3785

http://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/letras-maiusculas-minusculas-circunstancias-uso.html

Quanto a outras situações, quando existem frases entre parêntesis, o texto que se segue também começará por norma com letra minúscula e a pontuação será inserida dentro dos parêntesis. Por exemplo:
- Ele ganhou o primeiro lugar (quem diria, hein?) do concurso nacional.
- Ele surpreendeu-nos (que alegria!) com a sua chegada.

Porém se a frase entre parêntesis constituir uma frase à parte colocada no fim de um ponto final, esta deverá seguir a norma geral e começar com maiúsculas.
Por exemplo:
- Todos se surpreenderam com aquela atitude. (Ninguém estava à espera do que aconteceu!)
- A sociedade está corrompida. (Será isto um facto inédito?)

Mais informações aqui:

http://www.alunosonline.com.br/portugues/uso-maiusculas-minusculas.html

Ainda na sequência dos pontos de exclamação e de interrogação, por vezes estes podem assumir outro sentido dentro de frases, nesse caso, e se eles não forem utilizados como delimitadores da frase, utiliza-se a minúscula.
Por exemplo:
- Ah! sim? Até admira... - Neste caso a expressão “Ah! sim?” funciona como uma frase, não sendo separadas as duas palavras por estarem quase intimamente ligadas, sendo por norma pronunciadas como uma expressão só.
- Ai!, até admira!... - Neste caso, a vírgula está presente como delimitadora da oração e temos um “Ai!” com um valor significativo intenso (que leva a pessoa a acrescentar “até admira!”) que só nos poderia ser transmitido por meio de uma oração, pelo menos. Para além disso, neste caso, o ponto de exclamação serve para atribuir uma expressão ao “Ai!” que sem ele tomaria um diferente sentido.

Mais informações aqui:

https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/virgula-depois-de-pontos-de-exclamacao-e-de-interrogacao-novamente/4440

Comment: Excelente resposta Ana +1

Comment: Ana, não te terás enganado na regra A? O que diz no site do fanfiction é “sempre que o narrador interromper algo, ele virá em letra minúscula. Sim! Em todos os casos! Sem exceções!” Portanto deve ser: A ― Claro que tenho ― declarou. Sem qualquer pontuação depois de *tenho*. Isto corresponde ao exemplo deles: — Eu te falei, menino — ela disse raivosa.